# Parsing Decaf grammar in Antlr4

Tags: html-parsing, antlr, antlr4, grammar

I am creating parser and lexer rules for Decaf programming language written in ANTLR4. There is a parser test file I am trying to run to get the parser tree for it by printing the visited nodes on the terminal window and paste them into `D3_parser_tree.html` class. The current parser tree is missing the right square brackets with the number 10 according to this testing file : `class program { int i [10]; }`
[image: parser tree]

The error I am getting : `mismatched input '10' expecting INT_LITERAL`

I am not sure why I am getting this error although I have declared a lexer rule for `INT_LITERAL` and then called it in a parser rule within `field_decl` according to the given Decaf spec :

`** Parser rules **`

```
<program> → class Program ‘{‘ <field_decl>* <method_decl>* ‘}’
<field_decl> → <type> { <id> | <id> ‘[‘ <int_literal> ‘]’ }+, ;
<method_decl> → { <type> | void } <id> ( [ { <type> <id> }+, ] ) <block>
<digit> → 0 | 1 | 2 | … | 9
<block> → ‘{‘ <var_decl>* <statement>* ‘}’
<literal> → <int_literal> | <char_literal> | <bool_literal>
<hex_digit> → <digit> | a | b | c | … | f | A | B | C | … | F
<int_literal> → <decimal_literal> | <hex_literal>
<decimal_literal> → <digit> <digit>*
<hex_literal> → 0x <hex_digit> <hex_digit>*
```

Related Lexer rules :

```
NUMBER : [0-9]+;
fragment ALPHA : [_a-zA-Z0-9];
fragment DIGIT : [0-9];
fragment DECIMAL_LITERAL : DIGIT+;
CHAR_LITERAL : '\'' CHAR '\'';
STRING_LITERAL : '"' CHAR+ '"' ;
COMMENT : '//' ~('\n')* '\n' -> skip;
WS : (' ' | '\n' | '\t' | '\r') + -> skip;
```

Related Parser rules :

```
program : CLASS VAR LCURLYBRACE field_decl*method_decl* RCURLYBRACE EOF;
field_decl : data_type field ( COMMA field )* SEMICOLON;
```

Please let me know if you need further details & I appreciate your help a lot.

Comment: You'll need to post enough of your grammar file to reproduce the error. The most likely cause of your problem is that your `INT_LITERAL` rule conflicts with another rule that you did not show us. It would also be helpful if you printed out which tokens are being generated for your input, specifically what kind of token '10' is recognized as.

Comment: Yeah, what sepp2k said. Easiest is to edit your question and add you entire ANTLR grammar to it.

Comment: The generated tokens are: `CLASS - VAR - LCURLYBRACE-INT-VAR- LSQUAREBRACE - NUMBER - RSQUAREBRACE - SEMICOLON-RCURLYBRACE`. Seems good here in lexer rules and number 10 is recognised as `NUMBER`. I will add some grammar rules

Comment: @KhaledSalem I don't see a definition of `NUMBER` in your edited rules, but clearly that's where the problem lies. From the name I'm guessing that `NUMBER` and `INT_LITERAL` overlap heavily.

Comment: Easiest is to edit your question and add your **entire** ANTLR grammar to it.

Comment: @sepp2k I have `NUMBER` token and just added to the question !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following rules conflict:

```
VAR : ALPHA+;
...
NUMBER : [0-9]+;
...
INT_LITERAL : DECIMAL_LITERAL | HEX_LITERAL;
```

They all match `10`, but the lexer will always choose `VAR` since that is the rule defined first.

This is just how ANTLR's lexer works: it tries to match the most characters as possible, and when two (or more) rules all match the same amount of characters, the one defined first "wins".

You will see that it parses correctly if you change `field` into:

```
field : VAR | VAR LSQUAREBRACE VAR RSQUAREBRACE;
```

Comment: You're absolutely right, that has solved it correctly. Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome. Btw, I didn't mean for you to change `field` into `field : VAR | VAR LSQUAREBRACE VAR RSQUAREBRACE;` but rather resolve the ambiguous `VAR`, `NUMBER` and `INT_LITERAL` rules.